# how to create not cacheable helper method?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, cache, full-page-cache, varnish

We have written logic to find client IP address in the custom helper.

```
public function getIpAddress(){
..............
return $ip;
}
```

It works only at first hit after that it only displays the old cacheable value.

what is the correct approach to get the dynamic values in the cached pages?

**Note:** We have referred some links [link1](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html),[link2](https://www.siphor.com/add-private-content-in-magento-2/) but we don't need to display the value anywhere so we thought we don't need to use knockout js?

Comment: Are you trying to get client/customer remote address ip?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code...

```
 public function getRemoteIp()
 {
     return $this->getData(OrderInterface::REMOTE_IP);
 }
```

Here ***$this*** refer to **`Magento\Sales\Model\Order`** Object and 
***OrderInterface*** refers to **`Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface`**.

Comment: Thanks. Our server behind the proxy so it always returns 127.0.0.1 so I'm using alternate way. Also, getting IP address is not the problem for me now, it gets cached and it never changes that is the problem.